# How to create a simple shopping list (but not ecommerce)

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to create a way to create a list of items, similar in appearance to a cart. You have products, you add them to a list and can adjust quantity. The list will follow you throughout the site. However, price is not a factor, there's no payment processing. You're essentially creating a list of products that you want, where then you can submit them to the company. You'll then get a call from them. The products are bespoke so a standard x = $4 situation won't work here. I think something like the Commerce plugin seems like overkill and not sure it can do this (without payments anyway). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used it before, but it sounds like maybe the [Shortlist](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist) plugin might do what you're looking for.

Outside of that, sounds like it'd be a fairly simple [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) to [custom develop](https://pluginfactory.io).

Comment: This was exactly what the doctor ordered. Thanks!